# unless that computer toed the line -- what does "toed" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [Sams Teach Yourself Networking in 24 Hours, 4th Edition by Uyless Black (2009)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0768685761)

Example:

> At the risk of stating the obvious, the Internet has transformed the way we do business. Prior to its inception, it was quite difficult to transfer data from one computer to another—unless that computer **toed** the line and used the same proprietary procedures as the sending machine.

Looked in all the dictionaries online and I don't think there was a meaning that matched the one used in the example.

Comment: [Toe the line](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/toe+the+line) is an idiom.

Comment: Yeah. I thought they were talking about that line as meaning a wire.

Comment: I think it's not really a very appropriate usage in your cited context. Usually when we talk about metaphorically ***toeing the line*** it refers to some kind of "official standard". But in this *specific* context, the reason early computers couldn't freely exchange data was precisely because there ***wasn't*** an industry standard for networking. If two computers happened to use the same network protocol they could communicate, but you'd hardly say one of them *toed the line" to match the other one. Either they both worked the same or they didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["toe the line"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toe_the_line) is a phrase that means conforming to the rules.

> The primary connotation of "toe the line" is “to adhere to rules or doctrines conscientiously; conform” (American Heritage), “To conform to a rule or standard” (Oxford).

The author means that the computer had to conform to the proprietary rules of the machine that sent data if data transfer was to occur.